# How to detach and then reattach a Backbone.View without unbinding events?

Tags: javascript, dom, backbone.js

I have a Backbone system consisting of nested sub-views in which I occasionally need to do the following.

1. Detach a child view from the DOM
2. Re-render the parent view from scratch (from a template)
3. Re-attach the child view at the correct
   place

I do this by calling something like `$(parent.el).html(...)` and then `$(parent.el).append(child.el)`

What I have always seen with this technique is that the event handlers on the child are lost. So I have tried a number of things, none of which have worked so far.

1. Detaching the child.el first with `$.detach()`
2. Cloning the child.el node and reattaching the clone
3. Calling child.delegateEvents() again after reattaching

The only thing that works for me is completely rebuilding the child view from scratch. Does anyone have any ideas? Reattaching the existing node would be much more efficient.

Thanks!

Comment: removing an element from the dom, will automatically mean your dom events are gone so i doubt you can append the childview again without having to rebind the dom events. or are you talking about Backbone events?  (or both?)

Comment: The example at http://api.jquery.com/detach/ seems to preserve attached events. BB's delegateEvent uses $(view.el).bind/delegate, so it should work in theory.

Comment: `detach()` works as expected for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Xcrhb/1/

Comment: Re-rendering the entire heirachy has always been performant for me until ~2000 entries in a collection, at least under Chrome.  Why isn't this a good solution for you?

Comment: Are you running into visible performance issues?  If not, I agree with Elf.  Save yourself a lot of headache and re-render the entire thing.

Comment: Ok, that is where I have ended up. It creates another problem of making sure that all of the subviews are torn down properly, but that is easier to handle.

Comment: This fixed it for me: `this.$el.empty().html(...)` instead of `this.$el.html(...)`

Answer (score 3):

I just had a similar problem. This seemed to work for me:

```
this.undelegateEvents();
this.$el.hide();
this.$el.detach();

// do whatever here

this.$el.appendTo(containerElement);
this.delegateEvents();
this.$el.slideDown('fast');
```

I'm still not exactly sure *why* the event listeners disappear, though I can confirm they are actually gone when I look in the Chrome developer tools window. It's strange, because Roatin Marth has an example (http://jsfiddle.net/Xcrhb/1) where this problem doesn't occur.

Answer (score 1):

I do exactly the same.

```
// First of all pre-render child view
childView.render();

// Append in one place
parentView.$el.append(childView.el);

// Detach in another place
childView.$el.detach();

// And append it again
parentView.$el.append(childView.el);
```

Answer (score -2):

What you're trying to do seems to be hack-ish to Backbone. You would be better off using native functionality by setting up event delegation and re-rendering views instead of detaching, cloning, altering and re-attaching. You don't get any performance increase by doing it.

It would be much easier to help if you explained why you need to do it this way and why native Backbone way of doing things does not work for you.